# How to name computed attributes?

Tags: java, attributes, coding-style

I'm looking for some common conventions - if any - to name attributes when they are "computed". By "computed" I mean that their values are set by calling a specific method. Typically such attributes will not appear as parameter in the constructor, though they might be initialized within it.

Here is an example for a class Person where the age would be computed :

```
public class Person {

   Date birthday;
   int age;

   Person (Date birthday) {
       this.birthday = birthday;
       age = new Date(new Date().getTime() - birthday.getTime()).getYear();
   }
}
```

Comment: Give an example, I did not understand what you meant. Also, this might be very opinion-based.

Comment: just edited, I am also interested about comment tags to indicate such properties.

Comment: They are usually called Transient properties.

Comment: And what kind of conventions do you expect? Looks nice to me as is, I'm not sure it `age` should be named differently.

Comment: Perhaps derived values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In proper object oriented design, objects have properties, in a later phase the properties are identified as "real" properties or "derived" properties.

During development it is normal that "real" properties are encoded as attributes with a getter and a setter method (or just a getter method if it is a read only property like in your example the brithday of a person which is not supposed to change) and derived properties just have getters and thus from the outside it is invisible the underlying nature of the property which again is proper OO design. Internal mechanismes are to be invisible to the outside world.

During optimisations for performance one might decide to actually store the derived value in a variable inside the object and not calculated always when the getter is called.

A setter to one of the source attributes being called should also update the derived properties when they are being stored in a private variable.

If you use the Bean mechanisme sending property changed events, remember to also trigger property change events for derived properties when you change one of the source properties